# get availability all half an hour

Tags: java, jodatime

I have the following List in my application. Now I will detect every half an hour whether some date is in the scheduler. 
e.g.

27.09.2015: 08:00 - 13:00

maximum time range from 07:00 am to 07:00 pm

```
07:00 - 07:30 no -> 0
07:30 - 08:00 no -> 0
08:00 - 08:30 yes -> 1
08:30 - 09:00 yes -> 1
09:30 - 10:00 yes -> 1
...
13:00 - 13:30 no -> 0
```

and that should be the result:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ... 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 ...
```

I have approximately 1000 entries (80 user with an average of 12 entries = 960 entries)

If I iterate over the time ranges it will not be very performant. 
My question now would be if there is a performant way of doing this.
I use JodaTime but I didn't find an easy and performant way.

Thanks a lot for help!

```
final List<List<SchedulerContainer>> weekScheduler = new ArrayList<>();

weekScheduler.add(0, new ArrayList<SchedulerContainer>()); 
weekScheduler.add(1, new ArrayList<SchedulerContainer>()); 
weekScheduler.add(2, new ArrayList<SchedulerContainer>()); 
weekScheduler.add(3, new ArrayList<SchedulerContainer>()); 
weekScheduler.add(4, new ArrayList<SchedulerContainer>()); 
weekScheduler.add(5, new ArrayList<SchedulerContainer>()); 
weekScheduler.add(6, new ArrayList<SchedulerContainer>()); 

final SchedulerContainer sc1 = new SchedulerContainer();
sc1.setStart(formatter.parseDateTime("27.09.2015 08:00"));
sc1.setEnd(formatter.parseDateTime("27.09.2015 13:00"));
sc1.setContainerType(SchedulerContainerTypeEnum.SERVICE);
sc1.setRepeatable(true);

weekScheduler.get(1).add(sc1);

final SchedulerContainer sc2 = new SchedulerContainer();
sc2.setStart(formatter.parseDateTime("29.09.2015 11:00"));
sc2.setEnd(formatter.parseDateTime("29.09.2015 17:00"));
sc2.setContainerType(SchedulerContainerTypeEnum.SERVICE);
sc2.setRepeatable(true);

weekScheduler.get(3).add(sc1);
```

**[EDIT]**

I get this one from database:

```
 user1 -> weekScheduler 
 user2 -> weekScheduler 
 user3 -> weekScheduler 
 user4 -> weekScheduler 
...
```

and for my summary row in overview table I need this one:

```
 Monday

3 3 0 1 (for every half an hour)
```

[image: My table]

Comment: Where exactly in your code do you want to check the time ranges? Are you intending to check the time ranges of the `SchedulerContainer` or of the job the user will add?

Comment: I have e.g. 5 User with different SchedulerContainers - this Users I show in a table -> and the last row of the table should be a summary how many people are in the company (every half an hour)

Comment: So it is not about a job scheduler but more like a presence timetable?

Comment: Yes, it is a presence timetable - presence in half an hours - but I only have  a weekScheduler- List with the schedules (once again a list) of the days in it.